# Tomcat servier won't startup invalid CATALINA_BASE

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6, ubuntu-12.04

I had a tomcat6 server running in Ubuntu 12.04 (successfully).

I tried to install Jenkins through apt-get, not realizing that it would use the same port as tomcat6.  However, once I disabled Jenkins, tomcat6 still will not start.  I get the following error:

```
* invalid CATALINA_BASE: /var/lib/tomcat6
```

I have tried settings my `CATALINA_BASE` env variable to what I think it is supposed to be (/usr/share/tomcat6), but it hasn't seem to have had any effect.  Any suggestions?

I also tried setting `CATALINA_HOME` and `CATALINA_BASE` in `startup.sh`, but again no help.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently installing Jenkins completely uninstalled Tomcat6.

I decided to try to uninstall and reinstall Tomcat6 and, when trying to uninstall, was told that I Tomcat6 wasn't installed.

Installed Tomcat6 via apt-get install, and everything works as before.

There's probably more going on here that I don't understand, but the problem is resolved.